# Apache Felix bundle with Android GUI

Tags: android, apache-felix, android-gui

How can I create an OSGi bundle which I can inject in an Apache Felix container running on an Android devices which opens a GUI?

I am not interested in the details about converting a normal bundle to an Android bundle [1].
It's more like this 5-year-old thread [2] asking the same question. Unfortunately the response link is dead. Also these guys [3] seem to be able to do it.

So it is possible, but how? The responder of [2] wanted to add it to the Apache Felix docs. I cannot find it though.

- [1]http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html
- [2]http://apache-felix.18485.x6.nabble.com/launching-Android-GUI-as-a-felix-bundle-td4837411.html
- [3]http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mBS_SDK_7.3.0/modules/framework/common/demos/android/android_ui_demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [3] don't use Apache Felix, but their own proprietary OSGi runtime environment